# Erro de execução Play Framework

Tags: java, play-framework

Boa noite, estou estudando o Play Framework es estou batendo no seguinte erro:

```
! @6naojhb5b - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[MatchErro
r: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: sig=<A:Ljava.lang.Object;>(Lplay.
libs.F$Callback2<Lplay.mvc.WebSocket$In<TA;>;Lplay.mvc.WebSocket$Out<TA;>;>;)Lpl
ay.mvc.WebSocket<TA;>;, index=45, tp=<notype> (of class java.lang.AssertionError
)]]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(
HttpErrorHandler.scala:265) ~[play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.
scala:191) ~[play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at play.core.server.Server$class.logExceptionAndGetResult$1(Server.scala
:50) [play-server_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:5
9) [play-server_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:5
7) [play-server_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:522) [scala-li
brary-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at play.core.server.Server$class.getHandlerFor(Server.scala:57) [play-se
rver_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at play.core.server.NettyServer.getHandlerFor(NettyServer.scala:33) [pla
y-netty-server_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$8.apply(Pl
ayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:139) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$8.apply(Pl
ayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:139) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
Caused by: scala.MatchError: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: sig=<A:
Ljava.lang.Object;>(Lplay.libs.F$Callback2<Lplay.mvc.WebSocket$In<TA;>;Lplay.mvc
.WebSocket$Out<TA;>;>;)Lplay.mvc.WebSocket<TA;>;, index=45, tp=<notype> (of clas
s java.lang.AssertionError)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReloa
d.scala:44) ~[na:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReloa
d.scala:44) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44) ~[na
:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40) ~[na:na]

        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
 ~[na:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
 ~[na:na]
        at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:377) ~[scala-librar
y-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compile(PlayReload.scala:17) ~[na:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun
$apply$3$$anonfun$2.apply(PlayRun.scala:60) ~[na:na]
```

Não sei ao certo do que ele está reclamando, alguém que manja do play poderia me ajudar?

Estou usando o Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! É só um chute, mas o trecho `assertion failed: sig=<A:Ljava.lang.Object;>` me faz pensar que o método mapeado para atender à rota `/` tem uma assinatura incorreta. Pode postar o método e a rota, por favor?

Comment: Opa, este é a rota: "GET     /                            controllers.Inicio.index()"    e este é o método `public Result index(){
  return ok(inicio.render());
 }`

Comment: Tem algum parâmetro definido na primeira linha do seu template `inicio`?

Comment: Sim, este: @main("Top 100 filmes Cult")

Comment: Analise bem o código, pois tem algo errado que não esta vendo.

Answer (score 0):

Seguinte, mexi no meu código e agora o erro que ocorre na hora que executo o comando COMPILE é este:

`[play-new] $ compile
[info] Compiling 9 Scala sources and 5 Java sources to C:\play-new\target\scala-
2.11\classes...
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:compileIncremental for the full
 output.
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed:
 sig=<A:Ljava.lang.Object;>(Lplay.libs.F$Callback2<Lplay.mvc.WebSocket$In<TA;>;L
play.mvc.WebSocket$Out<TA;>;>;)Lplay.mvc.WebSocket<TA;>;, index=45, tp=<notype>
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 03/09/2015 23:12:33
[play-new] $`

e este é o erro que ocorre quando tento acessar LOCALHOSTE:9000

Execution exception

`[MatchError: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: sig=<A:Ljava.lang.Object;>(Lplay.libs.F$Callback2<Lplay.mvc.WebSocket$In<TA;>;Lplay.mvc.WebSocket$Out<TA;>;>;)Lplay.mvc.WebSocket<TA;>;, index=45, tp=<notype> (of class java.lang.AssertionError)]`

Se alguém poder me ajudar eu agradeço, att.

Answer (score 0):

Opa, passando para avisar que já resolvi o problema, em breve desenvolverei um tutoria passo a passo de como passar por esses problemas, att.